# Could not use gcc 10.2.0 even after installing it in macOS Big Sur

Tags: c++, gcc, macos-big-sur

I seem to have a problem with GCC compiler lately.
I installed **GCC compiler version 10.2.0** on **macOS Big Sur (11.1)**. My apple machine is still the **intel based** one. The details of Clang version and all is as follows:

```
jakehamster@Jakes-Air ~ % gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

One `brew install GCC` it says:

```
jakehamster@Jakes-Air ~ % brew install gcc
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: gcc 10.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 10.2.0, run `brew reinstall gcc`
```

And finally, when I compile a program which is supposed to have C++11/14 standards it says:

```
jakehamster@Jakes-Air codeforces % g++ 1360b.cpp 
1360b.cpp:14:17: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (int &i : v)
                ^
1 warning generated.
```

Please help me with this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not doing as the error message suggests and use the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` flag when compiling?

Comment: Sir is there any way that everytime I use 'gcc' it automatically uses '''gcc -std=c++17'''

Comment: Usually you have a build system that does that for you, if not, try making an alias in your command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile with `GCC` on mac like this:

```
g++-10 -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

Check version:

```
g++-10 --version
```

gives

```
g++-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0
```